# it's timeout when reading top 11 rows in a 100 million rows googlesheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api

in my googlesheet, it has more than 100 million rows,

and my code is :

```java
private Sheets sheets;

    @Override
    public Object previewDataset(String spreadsheetId, String tabName) throws IOException {

        tabName = tabName + "!1:11";

        var response = this.sheets.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, tabName).execute();

        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            log.info(MessageFormat.format("spid:{0}, tabName:{1} Data not found.", spreadsheetId, tabName));
            return null;
        }

        return values.stream();
    }
```

I set the readtimeout to 20s, but it still time out.

```java
2020-08-27 11:49:32.356 ERROR 7839 --- [io-13666-exec-8] c.s.i.i.c.common.GlobalExceptionHandler  : Read timed out

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:149) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541) ~[google-api-client-1.30.10.jar:1.30.10]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474) ~[google-api-client-1.30.10.jar:1.30.10]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591) ~[google-api-client-1.30.10.jar:1.30.10]
```

my question is i just only preview top 11 rows, why it always time out ?

Comment: Spreadsheets have an official limit of [5 million cells](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603). You don't want to go beyond that.

Comment: thanks,  this is a possible reason.  I found the real reason , the spreadsheet contained rich format , after i cleaned the format , it works well.